# keras(cnn+nn) predicting only one class among 4 classes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, image-recognition, conv-neural-network, keras

I am using two different datasets having 1200 images each. First dataset has 4 classes and second dataset has 6 classes.

This is simple image classification problem. But while training, on each epoch I am getting same value for validation accuracy for both the datasets.

I have resized all the images of both datasets to 100x100 using imagemagick.

I don't know where I am making mistake.
Thanks in advance

terminal output :

```
Using Theano backend.
Couldn't import dot_parser, loading of dot files will not be possible.
X_train shape: (880, 3, 100, 100)
880 train samples
220 test samples
train:
0 418
3 179
2 174
1 109
dtype: int64
test:
0 98
3 55
2 43
1 24
dtype: int64
Train on 880 samples, validate on 220 samples
Epoch 1/5
880/880 [==============================] - 582s - loss: 1.3444 - acc: 0.4500 - val_loss: 1.2752 - val_acc: 0.4455
Epoch 2/5
880/880 [==============================] - 540s - loss: 1.2624 - acc: 0.4750 - val_loss: 1.2802 - val_acc: 0.4455
Epoch 3/5
880/880 [==============================] - 540s - loss: 1.2637 - acc: 0.4750 - val_loss: 1.2712 - val_acc: 0.4455
Epoch 4/5
880/880 [==============================] - 538s - loss: 1.2484 - acc: 0.4750 - val_loss: 1.2623 - val_acc: 0.4455
Epoch 5/5
880/880 [==============================] - 537s - loss: 1.2375 - acc: 0.4750 - val_loss: 1.2486 - val_acc: 0.4455

prediction on test data:
In [26]: model.predict_classes(X_test)
220/220 [==============================] - 37s

Out[26]:
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

code:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
from keras.datasets import cifar10
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution2D, MaxPooling2D, Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.optimizers import SGD
from keras.utils import np_utils, generic_utils
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
import pandas as pd

batch_size = 30
nb_classes = 4 
nb_epoch = 10

img_rows, img_cols = 100, 100
img_channels = 3
X = np.load( 'image-data.npy' )
y = np.load( 'image-class.npy' )

# the data, shuffled and split between train and test sets
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split( X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=100 ) 
print('X_train shape:', X_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape[0], 'train samples')
print(X_test.shape[0], 'test samples')
print("train:\n ",pd.value_counts(y_train))
print("test:\n",pd.value_counts(y_test))


Y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, nb_classes)
Y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, nb_classes)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3, border_mode='same', input_shape=(img_channels, img_rows, img_cols)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(32, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, border_mode='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1,1) ))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(nb_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)


model.fit(X_train, Y_train , batch_size = batch_size, nb_epoch = nb_epoch,shuffle=True, show_accuracy=True,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test) )
out = model.predict_classes(X_test)
```

Comment: Add your network and optimizer.

Comment: i am using diabetic retinopathy dataset provided in this  [link](http://www.adcis.net/en/Download-Third-Party/Messidor.htmlindex-en.php)

Comment: It's possible that 100x100 images are simply too small to diagnose these diseases. Also try using Adam instead of SGD and let it run for more than just 5 epochs. More convolutions might also help.

Comment: i already tried with different optimizers and more epochs but no improvement.

Comment: Above network worked for another [dataset](http://lamda.nju.edu.cn/data_MIMLimage.ashx) with multi-label classification problem @aleju

Comment: Is your dataset imbalanced?